Why is an empty integer array filled with seemingly garbage data in C?
I'm currently learning C while following along with The C Book and one of the excercises is to write a program that lets the user input a number, which the program will spit back afterwards.
While troubleshooting my code I noticed that the array I'm putting the digits into is filled with... random data?

This seems weird to me. Is this normal? If so, why does this happen?
Here's my code:
int main() {
    int numbers[20], index;

    index = 0;
    int num = getchar();
    while (num != '\n') {
        numbers[index] = num - 48; // ASCII "0" starts at 48
        index++;
        num = getchar();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        printf("%d", numbers[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;   
}


Automatic variables are not automatically initialized.

This is normal for uninitialized local, non-static arrays (not the case with globals)

It wasn't filled at all and the original contents are indeterminate.

This is not specific to arrays, either. If you don't initialize index, it will have an unpredictable value.

thanks for the answers :)

Unless you explicitly initialize the values, or assign to them later, their values will be indeterminate. And in C using indeterminate values might lead to undefined behavior. It's our responsibilities as programmers to make sure our programs doesn't have undefined behavior.

On a different note, please don't use magic numbers, like the very implementation-specific value 48 for the character '0'. Use the actual character constant instead: num - '0'. Also first make sure that it actually is a digit (with the isdigit function), and also check that getchar() doesn't return EOF. With your current code, if there's an error or end of input, you will have an infinite loop.

@Markix, "I know that arrays are technically just pointers to allocated memory" --> Arrays are not pointers.  Pointers are not arrays.

@chux I swear I read somewhere that when you write the identifier of an array somewhere, you reference its pointer but I stand corrected then.

Arrays decay to pointers in many contexts, but that does not mean they are the same in other contexts.

@Markix An array decays to a pointer to its first element in most contexts.  That sometimes causes confusion.

Static arrays or arrays in global scope will be initialized. Local arrays with automatic storage duration like your numbers are not guaranteed to be initialized and the values they contain are indeterminate. The possibilities include the "garbage" values you're seeing.
Using these values without initializing them leads to undefined behavior.
Of note, the real danger here is that they could be what you expect. Maybe you compile in a debug mode and the array does get initialized to contain zeroes. Your program works fine, as far as you can see. Then you compile in a release mode, and code that you thought worked starts exhibiting very odd bugs.
Compiling with warnings on will help identify sources of undefined behavior. Compiling with warnings as errors will compel you to address the warnings.

There are exceptions to "Using these values without initializing them leads to undefined behavior."

In your answer, you wrote: "Using these values without initializing them leads to undefined behavior." -- This statement is incorrect. Using an object with an indeterminate representation will not lead to undefined behavior if its address is taken (§6.3.2.1 ¶2 of the ISO C23 standard) and the object does not have a "non-value representation" (§6.2.6.1 ¶5), which was called a "trap representation" in earlier versions of the standard. However, I believe your statement is correct for C++.
